# Lisp complaining with invalid function

Tags: lisp, newlisp

I write these code and compile with`newlisp`. I wrote these code:

```
(defun getdone ()(format t "we have a IDE for cLisp"))
getdone()
```

and the error message

```
ERR: invalid function : (defun getdone () (format t "we have a IDE for cLisp"))
```

====================

I finally realized that it is syntax error because newlisp's grammar is different from clisp's grammar. Now my code is runing well:

```
(define (getdone) (format "we have a IDE for cLisp"))
(getdone)
```

I don't know what is the `t` in `format t` used for ?

Comment: That all makes zero sense. You mention 'cLisp', but use 'newlisp' - which is a totally different Lisp with a totally different Lisp dialect. Then you write 'getdone()', which is not even Lisp syntax - still you claim that there is no syntax problem. You also seem to have done nothing yourself to find the problem, for example by looking at a manual or some tutorial. I propose you check what you actually want to do. The question is of very low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using newLISP, don't use

```
defun
```

use

```
define
```

to define all your functions.

if you're not using newLISP, your question's tags are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The function call should be

```
(getdone)
```

not `getdone()`.